# Remove Unwanted Wifi Driver from Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04, iwlwifi

I had bought this USB Wireless Adapter (Realtek RTL8188FTV) installed the WiFi driver for it but unfortunately twice. Now One is working correctly but I want to remove the unwanted driver which is not in use.
Can anyone please tell me How to check which installed driver is being used and remove the unwanted one. Screenshots below where two different WIFI network shown for only one USB Adapter connected

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you install the 2 drivers?  It could be that one works in concurrent mode

Comment: Firstly I installed the driver once, but the device was not working properly. It was not even scanning the network signals. Then I installed another driver from other repository without uninstalling the old driver.